# T-SQL count distinct and group by distinct IDs

Tags: sql-server, group-by, count, distinct-values

I have the following type of table:

```
BranchName CustID
========== ======
Branch1    1111
Branch1    1111
Branch1    2222
Branch2    2222
Branch2    4444 
Branch3    1111
Branch4    3333
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to count distinct CustID and group them by branches, without repeating any CustID.

Basically I'm trying to get to this:

```
BranchName DistCountofCust
========== ======
Branch1    2
Branch2    1
Branch3    0
Branch4    1
```

I tried this code:

```
SELECT X.BranchName, COUNT(DISTINCT X.CustID) as DistCountofCust

FROM

(SELECT T.BranchName, T.CustID

FROM MyTable T) as X

GROUP BY X.BranchName
```

It doesn't give correct result (doesn't count the number of CustID per branch correctly, because CustIDs overlap for certain branches). Is it possible to eliminate distinct CustIDs and group them per given branches? (In the final result I need only unique customers to be listed for branches).

Comment: What result set are you expecting? If it isn't working correctly, we need to know what you would say is correct. :)

Comment: It can be simplified to `SELECT X.BranchName, COUNT(DISTINCT X.CustID) as DistCountofCust FROM MyTable as X GROUP BY X.BranchName` however the code seems to be correct to me

Comment: @Larnu I've edited the question. I think I did not state properly what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `NOT EXISTS` for this. I'm assuming that branches have certain priority according to their name.

```
SELECT T1.BranchName, COUNT(DISTINCT X.CustID) as DistCountofCust
FROM MyTable T1
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT BranchName, CustID
   FROM MyTable T1
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM MyTable T2
      WHERE T1.BranchName > T2.BranchName and
            T1.CustID = T2.CustID
   )
) as X ON T1.BranchName = X.BranchName and T1.CustID = X.CustID
GROUP BY T1.BranchName
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=efafb8d0e63484c44f4b6e7693036048)

Answer (score 0):

One answer for you. As I say in my comment, ideally you want to have a separate table for your branches, as otherwise, when filtering your results, you can't do a count of 0 9as that would return no rows, and be omitted). This is why there is a second CTE to get the `DISTINCT` values of `BranchName`.

```
CREATE TABLE #Branch (BranchName varchar(10), CustID int);

INSERT INTO #Branch
VALUES
('Branch1',1111),
('Branch1',1111),
('Branch1',2222),
('Branch2',2222),
('Branch2',4444), 
('Branch3',1111),
('Branch4',3333);

WITH FirstCustomer AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustID ORDER BY BranchName) AS RN
    FROM #Branch),
Branches AS ( --really you should have a seperate table to store your branches in
    SELECT DISTINCT BranchName
    FROM #Branch)
SELECT B.BranchName,
       COUNT(FC.CustID) AS Customers
FROM Branches B
     LEFT JOIN FirstCustomer FC ON B.BranchName = FC.BranchName
                               AND FC.RN = 1
GROUP BY B.BranchName;

DROP TABLE #Branch;
```